# Funny characters returned from read function of Net_SSH2 library (phpseclib)

Tags: phpseclib

When I use the Net_SSH2 library and the read/write functions like this:

```
$ssh = new Net_SSH2($strServerIPAddress);
if(!$ssh->login($strServerUsername, $strServerPassword))
die("error");
$ssh->write(" service httpd reload\n");
$strApacheRestartResult = $ssh->read("[root@$strServerName ~]#");
$ssh->disconnect();
```

I get funny characters in the read function results ($strApacheRestartResult) that I dont see when running the same thing via Putty, see below:

```
service httpd reload
Reloading httpd: [60G[[0;31mFAILED[0;39m]

[root@server1 ~]#
```

Why are these `[60G[[0;31m` and `[0;39m]` in the return data from the read function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're ANSI control codes. Their purpose is to control the formatting of the text and the color and what not. To decode them properly you'd need a terminal emulator. phpseclib has one called File_ANSI:

http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/examples.html#top

Here's your code rewritten to use it:

```
$ssh = new Net_SSH2($strServerIPAddress);
$ansi = new File_ANSI();
if(!$ssh->login($strServerUsername, $strServerPassword))
die("error");
$ssh->write(" service httpd reload\n");
$ansi->appendString($ssh->read("[root@$strServerName ~]#"));
echo $ansi->getScreen();
$ssh->disconnect();
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I just remove all the control characters and what not, so the output is just plain?

Comment: The bottom of the URL I linked to addresses that. `htmlspecialchars_decode(strip_tags($ansi->getScreen()))`